# how to permanently merge two images

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

i have two different images and what i wanted to do is to overlap the 2nd image on the 1st image. i was trying to create an id card on my webpage but my problem is when my page resize the 2nd image lost its alignment...

the 1st image is a blob which will be the background.. the 2nd image is a qr code generated..

```
<img id="imgko" src=" <?php echo json_decode($bg);?>" style="position:relative; margin: auto;display: block; width: 100%; height: auto;">
<img id="qrko" src="" style="position: absolute;top: 285px;left: 630px;">
```

is there a way to permanently attach the 2nd image to the 1st image so that whenever the browser resize it wont affect the position of both images in jquery?.

Comment: Create a container which contains both images and use position: relative in that. You can do this with html and css, no javascript needed. Would be simpler to just use css3s multiple backgrounds though.

Comment: i was trying to create an id card.. i put both `img` tag inside `modal-body`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but, if you want to overlap two images in the same position, you have to create a container (which will contain both images and positionate it relative (to avoid the images that will be position as absolute to leave the container).

HTML should looks something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="overlaping" src="your first image">
    <img class="overlaping" src="your second image">
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    width:500px //or whatever desired size
    height:500px //or whatever desired size
}
.overlaping{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: what my question exactly is on how to permanently attach the 2nd image to the 1st image so whenever the browser resize it wont affect the position of the 2nd image.

Comment: what do you mean for "attach" @LionSmith? Do you want to create multiple backgrounds with both images?

Comment: no.. what i mean is to attach the 2nd image to the 1st image.. it is like the 1st image will be the background.. then the 2nd image is the image of the user..

Comment: Maybe playing with the opacity property of the image with the code above may help you